# A cyclic group contains a normal subgroup of prime index

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be finite cyclic goup. I want to show that $G$ contains a normal subgroup of prime index.

A group $G$ is cyclic if $G= \langle a \rangle$, for some $a\in G$.

A finite cyclic group of order $n$ contains a subgroup of order $m$ for each positive integer $m$ which divides $n$.

Comment: Isn't it clear that the statement you are trying to prove follows immediately from your third sentence?

Comment: @DerekHolt the statement that i wont to prove that $G$ contain subgroup of prime index

Comment: And isn't that clear from your third sentence? For example a group of order $100$ contains a subgroup of order $50$ , which has prime index.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$ and there is an $m$ such that $m|n$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $m$.  Furthermore, every subgroup of an abelian group is normal, and every cyclic group is abelian.

Can you see why these facts will get you the result you want?  I'll leave their proofs and the finer details to you.

Comment: yes i know this my problem is i could'nt complete this prove

Comment: So if $m|n$, consider the subgroup $H = \langle g^{n/m} \rangle$.  What is the order of $H$?  For the other results, can you see why cyclic groups are abelian?  Can you see why subgroups of abelian groups are normal?  For these, go back to the original definitions, and the desired result comes out pretty fast.

Comment: of course they are clear ,my problem was " subgroup of prime index" but it is ok now thanks

Comment: Ohh, sorry about that; I wasn't sure exactly where you were getting stuck.  For a finite group $G$, the index of a subgroup $H \subset G$ is just going to be $|G|/|H|$.  So if you want a subgroup $H$ of index $p$, you want $|H| = |G|/p$.

Comment: yes exactly; thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $a$ has order $n$, $a^k$  has order $\dfrac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take the prime factorization of $n:=|G|$, say:
$$n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_k^{\alpha_k}$$
By your third sentence, $G$ has in particular a subgroup $H$ of order $$m:=p_1^{\alpha_1-1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_k^{\alpha_k}$$
(because $m\mid n$) and this subgroup is normal, as any subgroup of an abelian group. Finally: $$[G:H]=|G|/|H|=n/m=p_1$$
which is a prime (and this holds for each $p_i$).